# Nonnegative Matrix Factorization - Interpreting clustering indicator matrix

Tags: clustering, matrix, matrix-decomposition, non-negative-matrix-factorization

In non-negative matrix factorization (NMF), the problem is to minimize $A - WH$. Dimensions are $A$ (m x n), $W$ (m, k) and $H$ (k, n). The matrix $H$ reveals soft clustering assignments of $n$ items over $k$ clusters, and is called clustering indicator matrix. Values in $H$ are constrained to have nonnegative numbers.

I am wondering how to properly interpret this $H$ matrix. There doesn't seem to be constraint (other than nonnegativity constraint) on the range of values that entries in $H$ can take. I'd like to perhaps have a row-wise sum of 1 for all rows in $H$. So, for a given row (cluster), I could perhaps interpret values probabilitisticallly. Would it be correct to simply divide each row's elements by row-sum? I am worried that it's not correct interpretation but I am not able to figure out why.

Comment: This is a nice question (+1) but can you please provide some references on how you came across this characterisation of $H$? I suspect you referr to the associations of NNMF and spectral clustering but these are usually associated with symmetric NNMF so your second paragraph threw me a bit off about the "no constraints" part.

Comment: Welcome to the CV community.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(W, H)$ be a solution to the NMF problem. Define $D$ to be the diagonal matrix with $D_ii = \sum_{j=1}^n H_{ij}$, so that (assuming $H$ has no all-0 rows), $D^{-1} H$ is the version of $H$ scaled to have row sums 1. But then $W H = W (D D^{-1}) H = (W D) (D^{-1} H)$, so $(W D, D^{-1} H)$ is an equally-good NMF solution (up to the regularization terms).

So yes, it's fine to rescale $H$ to have row sums 1 as long as long as you also scale the columns of $W$ accordingly. Whether a probabilistic interpretation is appropriate, though, depends on the problem setting.

Comment: While not wrong, I fail to see how this answers this question by the OP mostly because the OP's question is unclear... You seem to address one of the general comments ("*I'd like to perhaps have a row-wise sum of 1 for all rows in $H$*) but then again given that the OP has done clustering an integral part of her post this seems to miss the mark. Anyway, +1 for your time and for writing something hopefully relevant!